# Scrolling down marquee buttons

Tags: marquee

Hello im trying to make a scrolling down text ( like marquee but with no space between the messages)  the problem is that i want to have 2 buttons that will change the scrolling, for example if i click the button with the arrow pointing up the text will move up.
Thanks in advance for any answers!
Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
<style type="text/css">

#marqueecontainer{
position: relative;
width: 260px; /*marquee width */
height: 360px; /*marquee height */
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
padding: 2px;
padding-left: 4px;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">



var delayb4scroll=2000 //Specify initial delay before marquee starts to scroll on page (2000=2 seconds)
var marqueespeed=2 //Specify marquee scroll speed (larger is faster 1-10)
var pauseit=1 //Pause marquee onMousever (0=no. 1=yes)?

////NO NEED TO EDIT BELOW THIS LINE////////////

var copyspeed=marqueespeed
var pausespeed=(pauseit==0)? copyspeed: 0
var actualheight=''

function scrollmarquee(){
if (parseInt(cross_marquee.style.bottom)>(actualheight*(-1)+8))
cross_marquee.style.bottom=parseInt(cross_marquee.style.bottom)-copyspeed+"px"
else
cross_marquee.style.bottom="0px"
}

function initializemarquee(){
 cross_marquee=document.getElementById("vmarquee")
 cross_marquee.style.bottom=0

 marqueeheight=document.getElementById("marqueecontainer").offsetHeight
 actualheight=cross_marquee.offsetHeight;
 var div=cross_marquee.cloneNode(true);
 div.style.left='0px';
 div.style.bottom=actualheight+'px';
 cross_marquee.appendChild(div);
 if (window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Netscape/7")!=-1){ //if Opera or Netscape 7x, add scrollbars to scroll and exit
  cross_marquee.style.height=marqueeheight+"px"
  cross_marquee.style.overflow="scroll"
  return
 }
 setTimeout('lefttime=setInterval("scrollmarquee()",30)', delayb4scroll)
}

if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", initializemarquee, false)
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", initializemarquee)
else if (document.getElementById)
window.onload=initializemarquee


</script></head>

<body>
<div id="marqueecontainer" onMouseover="copyspeed=marqueespeed" onMouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">
<div id="vmarquee" style="position: absolute; width: 98%;">


<p>Message 1 </p>

</div>
</div>
<input style="position: absolute; left: 902px; top: 153px;"   type="image" width="35" height="35" src="../images/arrow-button-up.png" onmouseover="changeMarquee('up')" onmouseout="changeMarquee('speedup')" id="upBtn" value="Marquee up" /> 
  <input style="position: absolute; left: 902px; top: 518px;"   type="image" width="35" height="35" src="../images/arrow-button-down.png" onmouseover="changeMarquee('down')"   onmouseout="changeMarquee('speeddown')" onfocus="" onclick="" id="downBbtn" value="Marquee down" />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should show us the format of the content in the marquee. If your using DIVs for each line of content then the scrolling may be suboptimal (for the user), just removing the last piece of content and adding it to the beginning might be nicer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a JavaScript that might be able to help you out. http://jsfiddle.net/HZSVE/3/

Instead of doing pixel wise scrolling it takes the inner elements of the marquee and, appends the first element to the bottom for scrolling down or inserts the last element to the beginning for scrolling up.

```
var vmElm = document.getElementById("vmarquee");
var vmBtnDown = document.getElementById("vmdown");
var vmBtnUp = document.getElementById("vmup");

var startTime = 2000;
var scrollTime = 500;
var scrollDown = true;
var paused = false;

vmElm.onmousemove = function() {
    paused=true; 
};
vmElm.onmouseout = function() {
    paused=false; 
};
vmBtnDown.onclick = function() {
    scrollDown = true;
};
vmBtnUp.onclick = function() {
    scrollDown = false;
};
function vmScroll() {
    if(!paused) {
        var par = vmElm;
        var elms = par.getElementsByTagName("div");
        var elm;
        if(scrollDown) {
            elm = elms[0];
            par.removeChild(elm);
            par.appendChild(elm);
        } else {
            elm = elms[elms.length - 1];
            par.removeChild(elm);
            par.insertBefore(elm, elms[0]);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(vmScroll, scrollTime);
}

setTimeout(vmScroll, startTime);
```

Comment: How i can make it move smoothly??

Comment: How i can make it move smoothly??and i want to change the speed when i mouseover the buttons and i cant find a way to change buttons icons. another problem i got is that when i make mouseover the buttons it is like the marque moves down. sorry im new to all this.

Comment: @Ant Mar - Smoothness is difficult to simulate with this method. You change the speed with the scrollTime variable. You can make the buttons anything you want, IMG, A, input type=image, as long as they have the uique ID of vmBtnUp and vmBtnDown (in my script).

Comment: ok thx check this here plz i found this code and its simpler but got some problems thx! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592073/marque-like-with-javascript

Comment: @Ant Mar - that could just moves the 'hidden' scrollbar of a div every timer tick. It doesn't loop around, which is why it's simpler.